# How to turn a tensor product into a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I would like to do an operation on a matrix acting on a tensor product vector space that is a bit unusual. It is similar to a [partial trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace), but not quite that. Say I have a tensor product vector space $V \otimes V$. What I would like to be able to do, is a *linear* map from $L(V \otimes V)$ to $L(V)$ defined through:

$$
A \otimes B \to AB.
$$

In other words I want to turn a tensor product into a normal matrix product.

Assuming the usual [Kronecker product convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) for the tensor products, how can I compute this operation for an arbitrary matrix $T \in L(V \otimes V)$ (so $T$ can not necessarily be written as a simple tensor product)?

I know that in "tensor terminology" this is a contraction of two indices, if $T$ was viewed as a rank four tensor, I'm just not sure how to actually do it given a representation of $T$ as a matrix.

Comment: By the universal property, for every bilinear function $g:L(V)\times L(V)\rightarrow L(V)$, we have its linearization $G:L(V)\otimes L(V)\rightarrow L(V)$, defined by the formula $G(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\otimes B_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n g(A_i,B_i)$. Now, let $g(A,B)=AB$.  Remember that $L(V\otimes V)\simeq L(V)\otimes L(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard if you already know about the partial trace.  Recall that for $A \otimes B \in V \otimes V$, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\tr_1(A \otimes B) = \tr(A)B\\
\tr_2(A \otimes B) = \tr(B) A\\
\tr(A \otimes B) = \tr(A) \tr(B)
$$
So, given an arbitrary $T \in V \otimes V$, define
$$
p(T) = \frac{\tr_2(T)\tr_1(T)}{\tr(T)}
$$
And verify that, whenever $T = A \otimes B$, $p(T) = AB$.

Comment: Oh, I see now that my question wasn't well defined. I actually ment for the operation to be linear, meaning $\sum_n A_n \otimes B_n$ goes to $\sum_n A_n B_n$. This should uniquely define a linear map, I hope. But I don't think the one you gave is the one I'm after. I have edited my question to emphasize that the map should be linear.

Comment: My mistake.  I think you're right about all that.